# Weird keyboard behavior in my iOS app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, xcode4

Ok, so here's how my keyboard behaves:
There's a button which calls a method to send a textmessage, that works fine. If the user now sends the text everything's fine. 
Now if (s)he taps cancel it switches back to my view (as it's supposed to do), but the keyboard won't show up. I already tried

```
- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result {
   [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
   [inputView becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

since it didn't work I tried:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
   [inputView becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

but that won't work either. So how can I get my keyboard to show up?

EDIT: inputText is an UITextView.

Comment: What is inputView? In order for the keyboard to come up, whatever object your calling becomeFirstResponder on needs to be able to take text input.

Comment: I'm sorry. inputView is a UITextView. That should be able to take text input ;)

Comment: You're dismissing the view controller in the same method as you're setting the inputView to become the first responder. Does this view controller's view that your dismissing contain inputView? If so, you're getting rid of it.

Comment: nope, i have my 'rootview' that contains inputView. that 'rpptview' calls up the modalviewcontroller. (the sms dialog).as soon as that one is dismissed it switched back to my 'rootview' where i want the keyboard to show up...

Comment: Have you tried checking the return value of `[inputView canBecomeFirstResponder]` before calling `becomeFirstResponder`? Does it return YES?

Comment: Also, try setting the animated parameter in `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated` to NO.

Comment: @Akshay: Yep, it resturn YES. and WOW, that works... If I only knew why...

Comment: Great! I am adding this as an answer so that it helps others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be related to sending YES in `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:`. When animations are involved, statements generally don't remain synchronous. So, your call to `[inputView becomeFirstResponder]` must be executing before the modal dialog has been dismissed, resulting in an inconsistent state. This is the reason why the `inputView` does not take focus.

HTH,

Akshay